# GRASS GIS change raster output size?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, watershed, r.watershed

I have a large inut raster geotiff map of size 12000x9000.
I am running r.watershed to output a stream raster map. However it is much lower resolution, only about 960x711.
How do I make GRASS GIS / r.watershed command output a matching size raster map of same resolution of my input?

Comment: You need to use `g.region` here (or the corresponding entry in the map legend context menu). For the concept, see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region

Comment: @markusN Please consider adding your comment as an answer.

Comment: Which parameter is it - rows/cols or res or nsres/ewres?

Comment: if your are concerned about 2D grid resolution and using square cells, go to "Resolution" tab > "2D grid resolution" box put 0.5 for a 50cmx50cm resolution. In commandline, this is 'res=value' parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, GRASS GIS is ready for [massive data analysis](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_GIS_Performance).

In your case, you need to use [g.region](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/g.region.html), by using the corresponding entry in the map legend context menu (right mouse button on legend entry) or on command line (generic example):

```
g.region raster=your_raster_map -p
```

It will then use bounding box and raster resolution to set the computational region.

For the underlying concept, see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region .